# Why does this function only print first row of the table?

Tags: python, sqlite, pysimplegui

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import sqlite3


con = sqlite3.connect("BakeryDatabase.db")

cur = con.cursor()

dic={}
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Customer_Info')
dic['Customer_Info']=cur.fetchall()

def customerinfo():
    for row in range(len(dic['Customer_Info'])):
        print(dic['Customer_Info'][row])
        sg.theme('LightYellow')
        event, values  = sg.Window('Customers Information', [[sg.Text('Please select option.')],
                        [sg.Button('Add'),
                        sg.Button('Delete'), 
                        sg.Button('Modify'), 
                        sg.Cancel()]]).read(close=True)
```

When called this function only prints first row of the table. I would like it to print out entire table so the user can then decide what they want to change. Also when I click any of the buttons the output prints out next row until the entire table is shown.

Comment: I am not a python gui, but I would say loop simply with `for row in dic['Customer_Info']:`. See [example in w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_select.asp).

Answer (score 0):

First - your iteration over a dictionary seems odd, as pointed out in one of the comments.

Second:
Why do you fetch all rows to a dictionary and then iterate over it? you can directly iterate over a cursor:

```
for row in cur:
    ... do something with the row
```